# Pagination displaying only one result on every page

Tags: php, html, pagination

This is the code in the page where I display all the info I want. The problem is that I want it to show 5 results per page. Now, it's showing just 1 result on every page, and it's the same result on every page.

The following is my pagination code

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if(!con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database.table ORDER BY id DESC");
$total_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

$base_url = 'índex.html';
$per_page = 5;
$num_links = 5;
$total_rows = $total_rows;
$cur_page = 1;

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $cur_page = $_GET['page'];
    $cur_page = ($cur_page <1)? 1 : $cur_page;
}

$offset = ($cur_page-1)*$per_page;
$pages = ceil($total_rows/$per_page);

$start = (($cur_page - $num_links) > 0) ? ($cur_page - ($num_links - 1)) : 1;
$end = (($cur_page + $num_links) < $pages) ? ($cur_page + $num_links) : $pages;

$res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database.table LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$offset);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

The following is my code to display pagination page numbers. I think that this works fine. not sure tho.

```
        <?php
            if(isset($pages))
            {  
                if($pages > 1)        
                {    if($cur_page > $num_links)     // for taking to page 1 //
                    {   $dir = "first";
                        echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.(1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                    }
                   if($cur_page > 1) 
                    {
                        $dir = "prev";
                        echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($cur_page-1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                    }                 

                    for($x=$start ; $x<=$end ;$x++)
                    {

                        echo ($x == $cur_page) ? '<strong>'.$x.'</strong> ':'<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
                    }
                    if($cur_page < $pages )
                    {   $dir = "next";
                        echo '<span id="next"> <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.($cur_page+1).'">'.$dir.'</a> </span>';
                    }
                    if($cur_page < ($pages-$num_links) )
                    {   $dir = "last";

                        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$pages.'">'.$dir.'</a> '; 
                    }   
                }
            }
        ?>
<?php
```

### This is the the page where i display it on.

```
include("pagination.php");

$f1=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_name");
$f2=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_lastname");
$f3=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_startday");
$f4=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_startmonth");
$f5=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_startyear");
$f6=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_endday");
$f7=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_endmonth");
$f8=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_endyear");
$f9=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_place");
$f10=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_review");
$f11=mysql_result($query,$i,"user_acco");
$f12=mysql_result($query,$i,"algemeen");
$f13=mysql_result($query,$i,"ligging");
$f14=mysql_result($query,$i,"bereikbaarheid");
$f15=mysql_result($query,$i,"service2");
$f16=mysql_result($query,$i,"prijskwa");
$f17=mysql_result($query,$i,"weer");
$f18=mysql_result($query,$i,"kwareisa");
$f19=mysql_result($query,$i,"titel");
$id=mysql_result($query,$i,"id");
?>

<?php $b=array($f12,$f13,$f14,$f15,$f16);?> 

    <?php

        if(isset($res))
    { ?>

        <table width="450" border="0">
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td width="300"  align="left"><strong><font size="5"color="#00aeef"><?php echo $f11; ?></font></strong></td>
    <td width="150" align="right"><strong><font color="#00aeef"><?php echo $f9; ?></font></strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
    <hr align="left" width="50%" color="#00aeef">
    <br />
    <table width="45%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="70%"><strong><font color="#00aeef">Algemene waardering</font></strong></td>
        <td width="30%"><strong><font size="6"color="#00aeef"><?php echo array_sum($b)/count($b) ?></font></strong></td>
</table>
<br />

<hr align="left" width="50%" color="#00aeef">
    <table width="450" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td width="10%"></td>
        <td><strong><font color="#00aeef"><?php echo $f19; ?></font></strong></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<table width="450" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="50"></td>
    <td width="300" align="left"><?php echo $f10; ?></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
<hr align="left" width="50%" color="#00aeef">
<table width="50%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="90%">Algemene indruk</td>
        <td width="10%"><?php switch($f12) {
    case "1": echo "<img src='../../../stars/1.png'>";
    break;
    case "2": echo "<img src='../../../stars/2.png'>";
    break;
    case "3": echo "<img src='../../../stars/3.png'>";
    break;
    case "4": echo "<img src='../../../stars/4.png'>";
    break;
    case "5": echo "<img src='../../../stars/5.png'>";
    break;
    case "6": echo "<img src='../../../stars/6.png'>";
    break;
    case "7": echo "<img src='../../../stars/7.png'>";
    break;
    case "8": echo "<img src='../../../stars/8.png'>";
    break;
    case "9": echo "<img src='../../../stars/9.png'>";
    break;
    case "10": echo "<img src='../../../stars/10.png'>";
    break;
}
?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ligging</td>
        <td><?php switch($f13) {
    case "1": echo "<img src='../../../stars/1.png'>";
    break;
    case "2": echo "<img src='../../../stars/2.png'>";
    break;
    case "3": echo "<img src='../../../stars/3.png'>";
    break;
    case "4": echo "<img src='../../../stars/4.png'>";
    break;
    case "5": echo "<img src='../../../stars/5.png'>";
    break;
    case "6": echo "<img src='../../../stars/6.png'>";
    break;
    case "7": echo "<img src='../../../stars/7.png'>";
    break;
    case "8": echo "<img src='../../../stars/8.png'>";
    break;
    case "9": echo "<img src='../../../stars/9.png'>";
    break;
    case "10": echo "<img src='../../../stars/10.png'>";
    break;
}
?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="22">Bereikbaarheid</td>
        <td><?php switch($f14) {
    case "1": echo "<img src='../../../stars/1.png'>";
    break;
    case "2": echo "<img src='../../../stars/2.png'>";
    break;
    case "3": echo "<img src='../../../stars/3.png'>";
    break;
    case "4": echo "<img src='../../../stars/4.png'>";
    break;


case "5": echo "<img src='../../../stars/5.png'>";
    break;
    case "6": echo "<img src='../../../stars/6.png'>";
    break;
    case "7": echo "<img src='../../../stars/7.png'>";
    break;
    case "8": echo "<img src='../../../stars/8.png'>";
    break;
    case "9": echo "<img src='../../../stars/9.png'>";
    break;
    case "10": echo "<img src='../../../stars/10.png'>";
    break;
}
?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Service</td>
        <td><?php switch($f15) {
    case "1": echo "<img src='../../../stars/1.png'>";
    break;


case "2": echo "<img src='../../../stars/2.png'>";
    break;
    case "3": echo "<img src='../../../stars/3.png'>";
    break;
    case "4": echo "<img src='../../../stars/4.png'>";
    break;
    case "5": echo "<img src='../../../stars/5.png'>";
    break;
    case "6": echo "<img src='../../../stars/6.png'>";
    break;
    case "7": echo "<img src='../../../stars/7.png'>";
    break;
    case "8": echo "<img src='../../../stars/8.png'>";
    break;
    case "9": echo "<img src='../../../stars/9.png'>";
    break;
    case "10": echo "<img src='../../../stars/10.png'>";
    break;
}
?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prijs/kwaliteit</td>
        <td><?php switch($f16) {
    case "1": echo "<img src='../../../stars/1.png'>";
    break;
    case "2": echo "<img src='../../../stars/2.png'>";
    break;
    case "3": echo "<img src='../../../stars/3.png'>";
    break;
    case "4": echo "<img src='../../../stars/4.png'>";
    break;
    case "5": echo "<img src='../../../stars/5.png'>";
    break;
    case "6": echo "<img src='../../../stars/6.png'>";
    break;
    case "7": echo "<img src='../../../stars/7.png'>";
    break;
    case "8": echo "<img src='../../../stars/8.png'>";
    break;
    case "9": echo "<img src='../../../stars/9.png'>";
    break;
    case "10": echo "<img src='../../../stars/10.png'>";
    break;
}
?></td>
      </tr>
</table>
      <hr align="left" width="50%" color="#00aeef">
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="85%">Vakantie weer</td>
    <td width="15%"><?php switch($f17) {
    case "1": echo "<img src='../../../stars/1.png'>";
    break;
    case "2": echo "<img src='../../../stars/2.png'>";
    break;
    case "3": echo "<img src='../../../stars/3.png'>";
    break;
    case "4": echo "<img src='../../../stars/4.png'>";
    break;
    case "5": echo "<img src='../../../stars/5.png'>";
    break;
    case "6": echo "<img src='../../../stars/6.png'>";
    break;
    case "7": echo "<img src='../../../stars/7.png'>";
    break;
    case "8": echo "<img src='../../../stars/8.png'>";
    break;
    case "9": echo "<img src='../../../stars/9.png'>";
    break;
    case "10": echo "<img src='../../../stars/10.png'>";
    break;
}
?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="85%">Kwaliteit reisadvies</td>
    <td width="15%"><?php switch($f18) {
    case "1": echo "<img src='../../../stars/1.png'>";
    break;
    case "2": echo "<img src='../../../stars/2.png'>";
    break;
    case "3": echo "<img src='../../../stars/3.png'>";
    break;
    case "4": echo "<img src='../../../stars/4.png'>";
    break;
    case "5": echo "<img src='../../../stars/5.png'>";
    break;
    case "6": echo "<img src='../../../stars/6.png'>";
    break;
    case "7": echo "<img src='../../../stars/7.png'>";
    break;
    case "8": echo "<img src='../../../stars/8.png'>";
    break;
    case "9": echo "<img src='../../../stars/9.png'>";
    break;
    case "10": echo "<img src='../../../stars/10.png'>";
    break;
}
?>
</table>
<hr color="#00aeef">
<table width="450" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left"><em>Waardering van:</em></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="200" align="center"><?php echo $f1; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $f2; ?></td>
    <td width="85"></td>
    <td width="20" align="right"><?php echo $f3; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="auto" align="center"><?php echo $f4; ?></td>
    <td width="20" align="left"><?php echo $f5; ?></td>
    <td width="5" align="center">/</td>
    <td width="20" align="right"><?php echo $f6; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="auto" align="center"><?php echo $f7; ?></td>
    <td width="20" align="left"><?php echo $f8; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<hr color="#00aeef">
<hr color="#00aeef">
<br />
```

Comment: Please stop yelling.

Comment: Turn off caps lock, shouty.

Comment: When you debug this, where does it fail?  Do the SQL queries have the paging values you expect?  Where do those values come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (you are using different table names when query `total_rows` and select 5 next rows):

```
$res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database.table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$offset.",".$limit.");
//mysql_close($con);
```

Try comment close connection! :-) you cant fetch later if you closed the resource

Comment: where is the part where you output results?